# Is 24'' QHD monitor good for programming?

Tags: monitors, displays

I am looking to buy a 24inch QHD monitor for office work ( programming ) and general purpose use but not gaming . 
Would text be too small on a 24inch QHD Display ? Some people over internet has suggested 2560*1440p looks good on a 27 inch monitor compare to 24inch .

Comment: What would your spending limit be ?

Comment: around $300 . I have selected 2 models 
[Lenovo l27-q10] (https://www.lenovo.com/in/en/accessories-and-monitors/monitors/home/L27q-10A16270QX0-27-inch-QHD-Monitor/p/65CEGAC1IN)   and  [BenQ BL2420PT] (https://www.amazon.in/BenQ-BL2420PT-Resolution-Designer-Monitor/dp/B00UAMYTR8) . 
But not able to decide which one should I buy .

Comment: I woudl advise you to go to a showroom and see